# Как получить ключ к DynamicResource из Binding в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

В WPF, в Xaml разметке, присутствует привязка к данным и к динамическому словарю:

```
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource menu_File}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FileCommands}">
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MenuItem Header="{Path=DisplayName}" Command="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

Приведенный код работает корректно; название меню берется из динамического словаря по ключу `menu_file`, из коллекции `FileCommands` корректно выводятся элементы меню с отображаемым именем `DisplayName` и выполняется команда `Command`.

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем: возможно ли использовать `DisplayName` как ключ для доступа к динамической коллекции?

Дело в том, что вышеупомянутые словари используются для смены языка интерфейса на лету. И если для заголовка меню `Header="{DynamicResource menu_File}"` язык меняется, то для подменю необходимо принудительное обновление.
Пробовал следующие варианты:

```
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource DisplayName}"/>
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey={Path=DisplayName}}"/>
<MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=DisplayName}"/>
```

и другие всевозможные варианты, но кроме как ошибок ничего не получал. Сам только начинаю изучать C# и WPF и прошу прощения, за возможно глупый вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос на самом деле хороший.

Так просто не выйдет. Для того, чтобы привязываться к данным из VM, и чтобы можно было их обновлять, необходимо положить в VM ключ для `DynamicResource`. (Это, как я понимаю, вы сделали.)

Теперь нужно привязаться по этому ключу. Есть несколько путей, общий смысл которых — привязать ключ куда-то, а на его изменении менять и привязку Dynamic Resource.

Например, можно так. Положим вспомогательный класс:

```
static class ResourceKeyBinding
{
    // стандартное attached property ResourceKey
    public static object GetResourceKey(DependencyObject obj) =>
        obj.GetValue(ResourceKeyProperty);
    public static void SetResourceKey(DependencyObject obj, object value) =>
        obj.SetValue(ResourceKeyProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResourceKeyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ResourceKey", typeof(object), typeof(ResourceKeyBinding),
            // callback при изменении значения ResourceKey
            new PropertyMetadata(OnResourceKeyChanged));

    // стандартное attached property ResourceValue
    public static object GetResourceValue(DependencyObject obj) =>
        obj.GetValue(ResourceValueProperty);
    public static void SetResourceValue(DependencyObject obj, object value) =>
        obj.SetValue(ResourceValueProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResourceValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ResourceValue", typeof(object), typeof(ResourceKeyBinding));

    // это будет вызвано при изменении значения ResourceKey:
    static void OnResourceKeyChanged(
        DependencyObject self, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // SetResourceReference устанавливает dynamic resource-привязку
        ((FrameworkElement)self).SetResourceReference(ResourceValueProperty, e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

Пользоваться так:

```
<MenuItem
    Command="{Binding Path=Command}"
    local:ResourceKeyBinding.ResourceKey="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"
    Header="{Binding Path=(local:ResourceKeyBinding.ResourceValue),
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Пояснение: мы добавили два attached property: `ResourceKeyBinding.ResourceKey` и `ResourceKeyBinding.ResourceValue`. Первое привязали через `Binding` к VM. На изменении первого на второе устанавливаем `DynamicResource` с ключом, равным текущему значению. Теперь `Header` привязываем к этому второму attached property через `Binding`.

---

В принципе, можно было бы упростить код, обойдясь лишь одним attached property:

```
static class ResourceKeyBinding
{
    // standard attached property ResourceKey
    public static object GetResourceKey(DependencyObject obj) =>
        obj.GetValue(ResourceKeyProperty);
    public static void SetResourceKey(DependencyObject obj, object value) =>
        obj.SetValue(ResourceKeyProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResourceKeyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ResourceKey", typeof(object), typeof(ResourceKeyBinding),
            new PropertyMetadata((d, e) =>
                ((FrameworkElement)d).SetResourceReference(
                    MenuItem.HeaderProperty, e.NewValue)));
}
```

и используя просто как

```
<MenuItem
    Command="{Binding Path=Command}"
    local:ResourceKeyBinding.ResourceKey="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
```

Но такое решение работало бы *только* с `MenuItem`, а вам наверняка нужно локализовать и другие типы элементов.

Comment: большое Вам спасибо, за более чем развернутый ответ! Предложенное Вами решение полностью решило описанную проблему, но возникла другая, связанная с некорректным отображением `MenuItem`. Я новичок на StackOverflow, но как мне кажется возникшие сложности выходят за рамки этого вопроса. Поэтому я создал новый вопрос [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562054).