# MenuItem при заполнении с помощью DataTemplate в WPF отображается некорректно

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, style

Имеется `MenuItem`, который с помощью `Binding` заполняется другими `MenuItem` элементами. 
Фрагмент XAML файла:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="FileCommands" Header="{DynamicResource menu_File}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Commands}">
<MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="InputGestureText" Value="{Binding InputGestureText}" />
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}" />
    </Style>
</MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
<MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Commands}">
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
```

При этом варианте меню отображается следующим образом:

[image: Некорректное отображение MenuItem]

При сравнении с корректным отображением меню, разница очевидна:

[image: Корректное отображение MenuItem]

Как можно увидеть, при некорректном отображении `MenuItem` элемент имеет две области выделения, внутреннею и внешнею, причем `Command` срабатывает только при клике на внешней области выделения.
При этом, если я меняю элемент в `HierarchicalDataTemplate` с `MenuItem` на `TextBlock` вот так:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Commands}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

, то отображается меню корректно, но с одной особенностью. Как мне кажется, из-за того, что используется не `MenuItem`, а `TextBlock` игнорируются символы нижнего подчеркивания, которые используются для быстрого доступа к элементам меню при зажатой клавише `Alt` и текст выводится как есть. Выглядит это так:

[image: Корректное отображение MenuItem с TextBlock]

Как мне думается это не единственное отличие `TextBlock` от `MenuItem` и возможны еще какие-либо подводные камни, с которыми можно будет столкнуться в дальнейшем.

Вопрос заключается в следующем: возможно ли корректное отображение `MenuItem` или придется пожертвовать возможностью быстрого доступа к элементам меню при зажатой клавише `Alt` (если это конечно единственное отличие `TextBlock` от `MenuItem`)?

Comment: вам сюда http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/5149692

Comment: @vitidev Могу ли я использовать с указанным Вами решением `HierarchicalDataTemplate`? Если "да", то не могли бы Вы привести пример использования? Если это Вас не затруднит, конечно.

Comment: Затруднит.Я не знаю насчет иерархии и проверить ничего не могу. Я вспомнил, что когда то боролся с этим двойным отображением (но в контекстном меню, без акселераторов и без вложенности), порылся в закладках и дал ссылку. Однако добавлю, что у ContextMenu и у MenuItem есть одно странное свойство UsesItemContainerTemplate и если глянуть сюда http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030750/how-are-itemcontainertemplates-used-when-populating-a-menu (посмотрите код xaml  в ответе),то как я понимаю тут делается иерархическое меню

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `Label` или просто [`AccessText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.accesstext.aspx) вместо `TextBlock`, там акселераторы поддерживаются.

(И у вас в »Öffnen« пропали точки над Ö.)

---

По поводу «некорректного отображения»: ваш `HierarchicalDataTemplate` определяет *содержимое* для автоматически создаваемого дочернего `MenuItem`'а. Если этим содержимым является другой `MenuItem`, у вас получается просто два `MenuItem`'а, один на другом. Конечно, это выглядит не очень правильно.

Comment: уж и не знаю как Вас благодарить! Получилось при использовании `AccessText`.

Comment: @XelaNimed: Вот и отлично, что получилось!